# Dynamodb hashkey rangekey query with additional filters (java sdk)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk

We are using java AWS sdk (1.10.10) to connect to dynamoDB instance and we have a hashkey-rangekey load query which returns us the data we need.

The query uses the sdk's DynamoDBMapper to get data as follows :

```
mapper.load(clazz, hashKey, rangeKey, config)
```

Now we have a have a requirement to add an additional filter on a column which is neither the hashkey or rangekey

What is the best way to do this  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use query api to add additional filter attributes (non key attributes). The additional attributes should be given on FilterExpression parameter.